# HTML Post Form group data into dictionary

Tags: javascript, pug

I have this object:

```
{
   "foo1":"value",
   "values": {
       "foo2":"value",
       "foo3":"value"
   }
}
```

And this object corresponds to a form (pug):

```
form(action="/foo",method="POST")
    p Foo:
        input(type="text", name="foo1", value="value2")
    table
        tbody
             tr
                  td
                       input(type="text", name="foo2", value="value2")
                  td
                       input(type="text", name="foo3", value="value2")
    input(type="submit",value="Submit")
```

When the form is submitted it gives me the data:

```
{
   "foo1":"value2",
   "foo2":"value2",
   "foo3":"value2"
}
```

Here's the question:
Is there any way I can map the result to the original data structure, short of manually assigning each one?

Comment: What technology are you using at the server? Node?

Comment: Yes, Node with express.